# implicit function that compares two closed classes in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.10, implicits, scala-implicits

I am working with a `Location` object from another closed API and it already has a `toString()` method that returns a `String`. I just want an `implicit` function that can compare two `Location` instances by comparing their `toString()` values.  So I will be able to go

```
val L1 = new Location(**Parameters for Location**)
val L2 = new Location(**Parameters for Location**) 
if (L2 > L1) { **do something** }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider providing an implicit conversion to an instance of type `Ordered`:

```
case class Location(x: Int, y: Int, s: String)

import scala.math.Ordered

implicit class LocationOrdered(val loc: Location) 
extends Ordered[LocationOrdered] {
  def compare(other: LocationOrdered): Int = {
    this.loc.toString.compare(other.loc.toString)
  }
}

val a = Location(123, 456, "foo")
val b = Location(456, 789, "bar")

println("a = " + a + " b = " + b)

if (a > b) println("a > b") else println("! a > b")
if (a >= b) println("a >= b") else println("! a >= b")
if (a <= b) println("a <= b") else println("! a <= b")
if (a < b) println("a < b") else println("! a < b")
```

In this way, you automatically get all the other comparison methods `<=`, `<`, `>=`, `>` for free.

---

As @AlexeyRomanov has pointed out, it is usually preferable to have an implicit `Ordering` in scope, because for example `List.sort` requires it as an implicit argument. The implementation would be even shorter than for `Ordered`:

```
import scala.math.Ordering
import scala.math.Ordering._

implicit object LocationOrdering extends Ordering[Location] {
  def compare(a: Location, b: Location) = a.toString.compare(b.toString)
}
```

This would allow us to compare the `Location` values like this:

```
val locationOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[Location]]
import locationOrdering._
val a = Location(123, 456, "foo")
val b = Location(456, 789, "bar")

if (a > b) println("a > b") else println("! a > b")
```

Comment: You generally want `Ordering`, not `Ordered`, for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's just...

```
implicit class LocationUtil(l: Location) {
  def > (l2: Location): Boolean = if (l.toString() >= l2.toString()) true else false
}
```